# Pytorch autograd raising the error: "Expected isFloatingType(grads[i].type().scalarType()) to be true, but got false" when loss.backward()

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on the implementation of an adversarial training. The following code does not work:

```
    for i, data in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader), smoothing=0.9):

        pc1, pc2 = data
        pc1 = pc1.to(device).transpose(2, 1).contiguous().float()
        pc2 = pc2.to(device).transpose(2, 1).contiguous().float()

        # train the discriminator
        net_gen.eval()
        net_disc.train()

        i_odds = torch.arange(start=1, end=pc1.shape[2], step=2)
        ...

        # train the flow extractor
        net_gen.train()
        net_disc.eval()

        flow_pred = net_gen(pc1, pc2)
        pc_pred = pc1 + flow_pred

        z_pred = net_disc(pc1[:, :, i_odds], pc_pred[:, :, i_odds])
        loss_flow = - z_pred.mean()

        opt_gen.zero_grad()

        loss_flow.backward()
```

I get the following error on last line: `Expected isFloatingType(grads[i].type().scalarType()) to be true, but got false.`

What could that be? For all I could check, the model and all the tensors are all type cuda.Float.

```
That is the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zuanazzi/anaconda3/envs/tomtom2/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1667, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/home/zuanazzi/anaconda3/envs/tomtom2/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/home/zuanazzi/anaconda3/envs/tomtom2/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zuanazzi/PointCloudFlow/flownet3d_pytorch/self_train_adversarial.py", line 452, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zuanazzi/PointCloudFlow/flownet3d_pytorch/self_train_adversarial.py", line 445, in main
    train(args, net_flow, net_disc, train_loader, test_loader, boardio, textio)
  File "/home/zuanazzi/PointCloudFlow/flownet3d_pytorch/self_train_adversarial.py", line 309, in train
    train_stats = train_one_epoch(args, net_flow, net_disc, train_loader, opt_flow, opt_disc, writer, epoch)
  File "/home/zuanazzi/PointCloudFlow/flownet3d_pytorch/self_train_adversarial.py", line 227, in train_one_epoch
    loss_flow.backward()
  File "/home/zuanazzi/anaconda3/envs/tomtom2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 195, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/home/zuanazzi/anaconda3/envs/tomtom2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 99, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: Expected isFloatingType(grads[i].type().scalarType()) to be true, but got false.  (Could this error message be improved?  If so, please report an enhancement request to PyTorch.)
```

Question originally asked here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/expected-isfloatingtype-grads-i-type-scalartype-to-be-true-but-got-false/67840

**Edit:** It seems that architectures based on PointNet++ layers cannot be used as Discriminator because they won't return gradients. That is currently more a theory than a claim.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the data type of `loss_flow` is not a floating point number (probably an integer type).

You need to verify that the output of your discriminator

```py
z_pred = net_disc(pc1[:, :, i_odds], pc_pred[:, :, i_odds])
```

is indeed a floating point tensor.

Comment: That was what I thought as well, in debugging mode I verified `(Pdb) z_pred.type()
'torch.cuda.FloatTensor'`

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi you need to check the data type of `z_pred.grad`. Is it possible your discriminator is not differentiable?

Comment: (correction) the discriminator is trained before the generator. I am using a FlowNet3D architecture for that, which is differentiable for all I know. However, I cannot check z_pred.grad because the grads on became available after loss_flow.backward() which is exactly where things break